# How do I parse a date where I only have the day name?

Tags: java, parsing, date

Given a String that is simply a day, for example, "Thu" or "Thursday", how would I get a java.util.Calendar object where the day String represents the closest String to today.  In other words, today is Monday, 3/26/29012, so if the String were "Thu", I would want to form a date that represents "3/29/2012".  If the String passed in is "Mon" and we're on Monday, I would want today's date.  In this example, "3/26/2012".

I tried this ...

```
            final DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
            java.util.Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dayOfWeekStr);
            final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            dateCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            dateCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, now.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            dateCal.setTime(date);
```

but it isn't working.  Once I set the date, the year and month results to 1970, January.

Comment: I don't see a variable named dateCal in your code.

Comment: I guess you want the closest future date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with

```
public static Calendar getNearestDateFromDayString(final String dayOfWeekStr,
        final Calendar startingDay) throws ParseException {
    final DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
    final java.util.Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dayOfWeekStr);
    final Calendar result = Calendar.getInstance();
    result.setTime(date);
    result.set(Calendar.YEAR, startingDay.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    result.set(Calendar.MONTH, startingDay.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    result.set(Calendar.HOUR, startingDay.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    result.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startingDay.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    result.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    while (result.getTimeInMillis() <= today.getTime()) { 
        result.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
    }   // while
    return result;
} // getNearestDateFromDayString
```

If anyone has a more concise solution, I'll accept that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Just put `.setTime(..)` ontop of the rest. Currently you are overriding your YEAR and MONTH changes by setting the time.

As Kevin noted, it might not work in all cases. For that reason I'd suggest you use a different approach: get only the `DAY_OF_WEEK` from a calendar, based on the parsed date, and set it to `now`. Of course, you should take care of changing the week if you need to.

Comment: I believe you'll also need week of the month. You'll also have to write the logic for the rounding scheme you want (up,down[default], closest).

Comment: Hey Bozho, That doesn't work.  Moving the setTime to the top simply makes me set the first Friday of the current month of the current year (if the input string was "Fri").  What I want is the upcoming Friday, or if the day is the same as today, today.

Comment: well, you'd have to do some more calculations - as suggested by Kevin, set the WEEK as well.

Comment: If the day is 3/30/2012 and the input String is "mon", I would want the result to be 4/2/2012, so I can't use any week of March.  Anything more detailed than "do some more calculations" is appreciated.